# How to unlock the "Madness" Digital Trip car in singleplayer/free roam?

Tags: watch-dogs

I was playing Online Free Roam when my friend and I spotted a player driving the car from Madness. I'm wondering if this is a bug or if you can unlock it somehow. Here's some screenshots of him driving it:

[image: Madness car in free roam]

[image: Madness car in free roam #2]

Comment: What is "Madness?"

Comment: Madness is one of the minigame (audio trip) available, where you must crush Lost Souls (humans) with the car on the picture. Was this on PC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mod which unlocks it for normal play. You can find it here
http://www.nexusmods.com/watchdogs/?
its called ulimate car on demand mod.

Comment: But it shouldn't be possible to be used in multiplayer right? I've seen it in multiplayer aswell and was wondering how to get it.
If so, if one should unlock it through the mod, I guess you'll have to unmod it before playing multiplayer.